# Key differences between Hyperledger Aries and Hyperledger Indy?

Tags: hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-indy, decentralized-identity

Both Hyperledger Aries and Hyperledger Indy are platforms for building distributed ledger applications
for identities.

What are the main differences between them? When to choose one over the other to implement a blockchain solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aries is the agent (client) part of a decentralized identity (ledger, DIDs, verifiable credentials) application that is intended to be agnostic to the underlying ledger/DIDs/verifiable credentials layer.

Indy is a decentralized identity implementation including support for a ledger, DIDs and verifiable credentials.

Initial Aries work was to move the agent work in Indy to Aries, and so the first working versions of Aries use Indy underneath for the decentralized identity components. Over time, those components will become pluggable, and additional decentralized identity components will be supported. Thus, major parts of the indy-sdk will be deprecated, as they are implemented in Aries.

For building solutions, you should always be looking at Aries to start. You will need to know what Indy does, but not the details. The only time you would need to dive into Indy is if you what to extend its capabilities to support your use case.

Answer (score 5):

The question is clear, what choice to make between Aries and Indy, we could also rephrase as follows: where to start from?
Indy represents, certainly, a base layer, Aries, at the moment, is the better choice for building identity app.  Indy, infact, provides: Blockchain network, DID’s implementation, and all features related to verifiable credentials. Aries, on top of it, helps to build apps which can communicate over peer to peer network through secured communication channel: DIDComm. From the user interaction point of view, Aries is integrated with identity apps and internally talks to Indy.  Aim of Aries, obviousely, is to build an interoperable communication layer that can be connected not only to Indy but also others blockchains framework.
Indy, as the first project in the Hyperledger family to build a decentralized identity, offers a real-time view of the transactions and its architecture is based on self-sovereign identity which enables users to have complete control over their identity. At the very beginning Indy was good to build an identity solution but, clearly, it lacks a peer to peer communication which is the heart of identity solution. Aries has filled this part. For building solutions there are lots of things that need to be considered but you should look at Aries to start

Answer (score 3):

For building a decentralized identity solution, Hyperledger Indy project was started. Evernym has donated the codebase to Hyperledger community and thus Indy was born.

In initial architecture, Indy was supposed to provide governance (Consensus), Verifiable Credentials, DID, and DID Communication between different entities and Hyperledger Indy has provided all the above except DID Communication which later gave birth to Hyperledger Aries.

[Indy Journey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvyqH.png)
Now the question is why don't Indy itself provide DID comm feature rather than relying on Aries

1: Hyperledger projects support plug and play architecture, detaching DID communication is a good decision for Indy to focus more on core identity party and Hyperledger Ursa was created for same reason to detach all cryptographic features from Indy.

2: Identity is a fundamental right of citizens, so in later times there would be thousands of service providers who offer Identity solutions and Interoperability would be a key factor. Keeping in mind, building a Ledger agnostic based clients is a good idea where Aries not only support Indy but it will support other Blockchain ledgers too.

So putting all pieces together, Indy is providing a core identity feature where Aries is just one of the clients who is availing those services. It is the same as the relation between Ethereum (Indy) and Web3 (Aries). For a development perspective, we need to be more focused on Aries to develop client apps.

Answer (score 2):

Aries primarily covers the agent part of Hyperledger Indy, which has been initially cevered by Indy-Sdk. It supports connections to other Blockchains (For now it's only for Indy ledger).

Whereas Indy covers the blockchain part as of now.

Answer (score 2):

in layman's:

- Aries is for communication between agents
- Indy is for cryptographic
  transactions (issuance/proofing/etc)